# Manually created polygon bounding box makes bent latitude lines after clipping sf object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, terra

I am trying to manually build a bounding box to clip sf objects with. I build the simple polygon using corner coordinates, st_polygon, and st_sfc, then set the crs to the object I want to clip with. However, once I clip it using st_intersection, the latitude lines slightly bent northwards.

I know that this has something to do with the crs, but I cannot crack this one for the life of me.

Example:

```
usa <-rnaturalearth::ne_states(country = c('united states of america'), returnclass = "sf")

lon <- c(-84, -75, -75, -84, -84); lat <- c(40, 40, 35, 35, 40)
pol <- st_polygon(list(cbind(lon, lat)))
pol <- st_sfc(pol, crs=st_crs(usa))

usa <- st_intersection(usa, pol)

ggplot2::ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data=usa)
```

[image]

Comment: right at the start of every script run sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)   do that now and run again (if you want s2 features check out the s2 package)

Comment: @mdsumner Wow! This is the trick I was hoping for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general, a line between two points on the same latitude is *not* a line straight along that latitude.

Of course, there is no such thing as a straight line on the surface of a sphere; the nearest equivalent is the *geodesic*, i.e. a segment of the great circle on which the two points both sit. Longitude lines are already great circles, so the line joining two points on the exact same longitude will have the same longitude throughout. This isn't true of latitude lines because they are *not* great circles (apart from the equator itself).

If you define a large enough rectangle in the Northern hemisphere, its Northern and Southern edges will bulge Northwards. In the Southern hemisphere, they will bulge Southwards.

If what you want is an area with boundaries of fixed latitude and longitude, then it is best to specify the co-ordinates with several points along each edge that stick to the exact latitude you desire:

```r
lon <- c(seq(-84, -74.99, len = 100),
         rep(-75, 100), seq(-75.01, -83.99, len = 100),  
         rep(-84, 100))
lat <- c(rep(40, 100), seq(39.99, 35.01, len = 100), rep(35, 100),
         seq(35.01, 40, len = 100))

pol <- sf::st_polygon(list(cbind(lon, lat)))
pol <- sf::st_sfc(pol, crs=sf::st_crs(usa))

usa <- sf::st_intersection(usa, pol)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = usa)
```

[image]

Comment: Allan- thanks for the solution, I appreciate it. Do you happen to know the CRS logic behind why this happens, though? I've done this elsewhere and have not had the same phenomenon occur. I always get mentally jammed up by CRS systems. Seems to me that if both layers are in the same CRS when they are intersected, this should not happen.

Comment: @RyanUtz I don't think this is really a problem with CRS as such. The problem is that the rectangle you are using to crop the map only has 4 points specified. "Straight" lines between points on the surface of the Earth follow geodesics (i.e. the shortest path between the two points). Longitude lines are great circles, so are already geodesics, but latitude lines aren't. That means that "straight" lines between two points on the same latitude will not be at a fixed latitude. The effect is only noticeable when you are trying to define a rectangle on a large area (more than a degree or two)

Comment: Allan- thanks for that note. Sometimes I feel like I revert to caveman logic when it comes to thinking about geographic data, especially when projections and transformations turn up (whether they are the root of the problem or not).